# Why can't I update my Ubuntu?

Tags: updates

Whenever I try to update my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10 this pops up:

[image]

Comment: choose some different server from settings--software & updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/trusty/utopic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

EDIT: What this does: it updates /etc/apt/sources.list to use the utopic packages stream rather than the trusty stream. This will upgrade the packages appropriately.

Comment: Wow my downloads are SO MUCH SLOWER in terminal:

Answer (score 1):

If `do-release-upgrade` does not work, try this instead:

```
sed -i -e 's/OLD_DISTRO_NAME/NEW_DISTRO_NAME/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Remember to replace `OLD_DISTRO_NAME` and `NEW_DISTRO_NAME` with the actual codenames.

After that, reboot.

EDIT: Some seconds late... :&